# What does the World Reset timer mean?

Tags: race-the-sun

Upon dying in *Race the Sun*, you're met with a screen that shows your score, your rank, your challenges, and something marked "World Reset."

[image: World Reset timer]

This World Reset has a countdown associated with it, but I'm not sure what significance, if any, it holds.

**What does this timer do?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Race the Sun tip screen]

The world of Race the Sun is reset every day, generating a new world to play in. The countdown is a timer until that reset, which also rolls over the Daily Leaderboards.

The time is currently set to 12am CST (UTC -6).